# Como saber si Insert QueryBuilder en Laravel se realizo correctamente

Tags: php, sql, laravel, querybuilder

Tengo una consulta de tipo `Insert` y necesito saber si esa consulta se realizó correctamente para realizar una consulta siguiente.

```
DB::table('fichas_medicas')
    ->insert(['Paciente_ID' => $user_data->ID,
            'Medico_ID' => $request->medico,
            'Centromedico_ID' => 1,
            'fecha'=>$fecha,
            'hora'=>$hora,
            'nro'=>1,
            'turno'=>'morning',
            'estado'=>'waiting'
        ]);
```

Esta es mi consulta... Necesito saber si la consulta se realizó para luego realizar un `update` de otra tabla.

Estoy trabajando con el QueryBuilder de Laravel, no estoy usando Eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Se me ocurren un par de formas para detectar si QueryBuilder completó su tarea

1. Try & Catch

   ```
   try {
       DB::table('fichas_medicas')
           ->insert(['Paciente_ID' => $user_data->ID,
               'Medico_ID' => $request->medico,
               'Centromedico_ID' => 1,
               'fecha'=>$fecha,
               'hora'=>$hora,
               'nro'=>1,
               'turno'=>'morning',
               'estado'=>'waiting'
           ]);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       dd($e); // Procesar la excepción, línea temporal para ver que hay en $e
       // Hacer algo más
   }
   ```
2. Asignar el resultado de la consulta a una variable

   ```
   $query = DB::table('fichas_medicas')
               ->insert(['Paciente_ID' => $user_data->ID,
               'Medico_ID' => $request->medico,
               'Centromedico_ID' => 1,
               'fecha'=>$fecha,
               'hora'=>$hora,
               'nro'=>1,
               'turno'=>'morning',
               'estado'=>'waiting'
           ]);

   dd($query); // Línea temporal para ver que hay en $query

   if ($query) {
       // Hacer algo más
   }
   ```

Try & Catch es un método común para procesar errores o detectar si una acción se completa satisfactoriamente. Yo te recomendaría esta opción

Comment: Sip, me habia olvidado de `Try-Catch` ya lo estoy implementando. Muchas gracias